# Bootstrap carousel images responsiveness

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, responsiveness

I have in my Bootstrap Carousel some very big images, which when I try to resize their height they stop being responsive and so when I resize the browser window they look stretched. How can I resize their height without affecting the responsiveness. If code is needed i'll post it.

Comment: Setting the width to 100% without a height attribute will scale the image to the full width of your viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not give width and height both to image or it will get distorted. Since you want it to be responsive or on full screen width, you should not give height to it. What you can do is, use some image editor to resize or crop the image accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that's right, i've also cropped the images and it works quite good now.